# calculating the difference between sum of two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, vba

I have a table and I am deducting credit and debit from the table to get my amount but the problem here is, it is reflecting in only one row, my credit row has value for only few rows and for the rest it is blank.

Sample table I have cost,profit,debit and credit , I am doing the difference between sum of debit and sum of credit to yield a amount the problem here is it is affecting only a single value

here is what I did

```
SELECT ACC, PROFIT, COST, PROJ,Sum(CREDIT),Sum(DEBIT),Sum(CREDIT)- Sum(DEBIT) asAMOUNT FROM SAMPLE_TBL GROUP BY ACC, PROFIT,COST,PROJECT;
```

I got the values as

```
ACC PROFIT  COST    PROJ    debit    credit AMOUNT

1000    1316    105472      18000       
1000    1316    614550      20000       
1000    1348    614576      16000       
1000    2032    616034      20000       
150700  1316    614550      1200    800 -400

150700  1348    614576      400
```

the problem here is, it is not affecting the remaining rows  in AMOUNT can I know the reason

Comment: I think that's because CREDIT column has NULL in other rows. If so use IsNULL(Credit,0) if you are using MSSQL or IFNULL(CREDT,0) if you are using mySQL

Comment: yes the column is null so how can i implement IsNULL with the Aggregate SUM function like SUM(IsNUll(Credit,0))

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you have `NULL` values in one or more columns.  If this is the case, the standard SQL way to handle this is using `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT ACC, PROFIT, COST, PROJ, Sum(CREDIT), Sum(DEBIT),
       (COALESCE(Sum(CREDIT), 0) - COALESCE(Sum(DEBIT), 0)) as AMOUNT
FROM SAMPLE_TBL
GROUP BY ACC, PROFIT, COST, PROJECT;
```

This replaces the `NULL` values with `0`.  It will work in both Oracle and MySQL (the two databases tagged on the question) as well as most other databases.

Comment: Yes, COALESCE is ANSI Standard

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL

```
SELECT ACC, PROFIT, COST, PROJ,Sum(IFNULL(CREDIT,0)),Sum(IFNULL(DEBIT,0)),
Sum(IFNULL(CREDIT,0))- Sum(IFNULL(DEBIT,0)) asAMOUNT 
FROM SAMPLE_TBL GROUP BY ACC, PROFIT,COST,PROJECT;
```

Replace IFNULL with ISNULL if you are using MSSQL